# Scala Play form validation: required boolean isn't mandatory

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I've found interesting thing in Play! frameworks form validation. For example I have such form:

```
case class Foo(mystring: String, myint: Int, mybool: Boolean) { // doing cool stuff here }
val myForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "mystring" -> text,
      "myint" -> number,
      "mybool" -> boolean
)(Foo.apply)(Foo.unapply))
```

When I'm binding data without "mybool" present in my Json, validation passes and creates an object with "mybool = false". This is quite strange behavior, as if I will pass the same data, but without "mystring" field I will get `Validation Errors: Map(mystring -> error.required)` which I expect to see - as the field is missing.

If I'm making the boolean field optional, but I'm manually adding such check:

```
"mybool" -> optional(boolean).verifying("mybool.required", _.isDefined)
```

And bind data without the field I'm getting the expected error:

```
Validation Errors: Map(mybool -> mybool.required)
```

Example data set:

```
{
  "mystring": "stringHere",
  "myint": 33
}
```

Why required check doesn't work for Boolean? What is the best workaround for it? Is it a Play! bug or I just don't understand something?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine it's by design. Typically if you have a boolean field then you would bind that to an HTML checkbox. If the box is checked when the form is submitted then all works as expected; however, if the box isn't checked then browsers don't send the field name with the submitted data. Basically, there is no different between an unchecked box and the element not existing at all, so Play has to assume (for boolean fields) that the value is "false".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sounds like an explanation. Then probably it's incorrect, that I'm using forms to bind my incoming data, which comes from API, not from HTML forms. For now I'll use the workaround with optional boolean and manual check.

Comment: If it does most of what you need then I see no problem with using Play's Forms whether the data is coming from a form submission or as an API request. I should say I'm not terribly familiar with Scala so there may be some built-in way of doing what you want, but sometimes it is necessary to do your own custom verification.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
val form: Form[Boolean] = Form[Boolean](
    mapping[Boolean, Boolean](
      "state" -> optional(boolean).verifying("state.required", _.isDefined).transform(_.get, Some(_))
    )(identity)(Some(_))
  )
```

Which would allow you to make the boolean field mandatory, overriding Plays default behaviour.

We often have radio buttons for `Yes` and `No` instead of check boxes and it works with that